# OTRS WebService SOAP TicketCreate not returning

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, otrs

I'm fairly new to OTRS and perl and i'm working with it for about 2 weeks.
I have been creating and modifying webservice operations in perl and testing them with `SoapUI`. The version of OTRS being used is 3.3.

Right now i'm facing a problem which i can't understand. When i make a SOAP request to call `TicketCreate` operation i don't always get a response on `SoapUI`. I found out that this issue seems to be connected with the values that are passed on the soap request.

If i use a certain `QueueID`, `ServiceID` and `SLAID` i get a response that tells me the ticket id, ticket number and article id from the created ticket. If use other `QueueID`, `ServiceID` and `SLAID` i get nothing, *not even an error*.

I have been putting outputs through `TicketCreate.pm` to see if the execution stalls and where. But the only thing i got to see is that everything runs and that until the last return on the code that everything is fine.

Comment: Would it be possible to get your code related to this issue?

Comment: Please check the web service log, via the Web Service Debugger, the OTRS log file or the web server log, in that order. You will most probably contain a pointer to your problem.